# Why Spring is trying to INSERT data inside different transaction?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I found some strange behavior in PostgreSQL & Spring declared transactions while have tried to write a simple test.
Let's take a look at it.
Suppose we have two such JPA entities:

```
@Entity
public class Foo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "foo")
    private List<Bar> bars = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addBar(Bar bar){
       bars.add(bar);
       bar.setFoo(this);
    }

    //getters,setters,equals and hashCode omitted
}

@Entity
public class Bar {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "foo_id")
    private Foo foo;

    //getters,setters,equals and hashCode omitted
}
```

Also we have a trivial repository:

```
public interface FooRepo extends JpaRepository<Foo,Long> {}
```

And it's Test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class FooRepoTest {

    @Autowired
    private FooRepo fooRepo;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        Bar bar = new Bar();
        bar.setName("bar");

        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.setName("foo");

        foo.addBar(bar);

        fooRepo.saveAndFlush(foo);
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public void testGet(){
        Foo foo = fooRepo.findOne(1L);
        assertThat(foo).isNotNull();
        assertThat(foo.getName()).isEqualTo("foo");
        assertThat(foo.getBars().get(0)).isNotNull();
        assertThat(foo.getBars().get(0).getName()).isEqualTo("bar");
    }

}
```

Application.properties:

```
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;MODE=PostgreSQL; DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false
#spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

spring.jpa.database=postgresql

spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">   


<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>transact-issue</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>transact-issue</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

After all I run the test and got:

```
        Hibernate: insert into foo (name, id) values (?, ?)
    2016-10-15 23:59:30.128  WARN 4764 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 25006
    2016-10-15 23:59:30.128 ERROR 4764 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: could not perform INSERT in read-only transaction 
    2016-10-15 23:59:30.128  INFO 4764 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
    2016-10-15 23:59:30.144  INFO 4764 --- [           main] o.s.t.c.transaction.TransactionContext   : Rolled back transaction for test context [DefaultTestContext@f8c1ddd testClass = FooRepoTest, testInstance = com.example.repo.FooRepoTest@60704c, testMethod = testGet@FooRepoTest, testException = org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement, mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@70be0a2b testClass = FooRepoTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.example.TransactIssueApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextCustomizer@527740a2, org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@370736d9, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@2b552920], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]]].
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.262 sec <<< FAILURE! - in com.example.repo.FooRepoTest
    testGet(com.example.repo.FooRepoTest)  Time elapsed: 0.063 sec  <<< ERROR!
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2103)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1836)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:512)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:388)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:334)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2897)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3397)
        at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:89)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:582)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:456)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1282)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1300)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:298)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy68.flush(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.flush(SimpleJpaRepository.java:553)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.saveAndFlush(SimpleJpaRepository.java:521)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:503)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:488)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy72.saveAndFlush(Unknown Source)
        at com.example.repo.FooRepoTest.setUp(FooRepoTest.java:34)
```

Where the main problem is here: 
`ERROR: could not perform INSERT in read-only transaction (it's my own translation from my native language)`

For me it sounds strange cause I don't insert any data in my `testGet` method. I marked it as `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` due to I use Lazy initialization collection.

If I did not mark it so I would get an error as follows:
`org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.example.entities.Foo.bars, could not initialize proxy - no Session`

If I marked it just as `@Transactional` or run `FooRepoTest.setUp` lonely I won't get any errors.

Now I don't understand such behavior cause I know that when I call `fooRepo.saveAndFlush(foo)` then it should be executed in it's own transaction since I found next code in `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository`:

```
@Transactional
public <S extends T> S saveAndFlush(S entity) {
    Object result = this.save(entity);
    this.flush();
    return result;
}
```

It seems that in this case Spring is trying to join two transactions or do something similar.

And finally one notice yet. IF I change DB from PostgreSQL to HB2 with PostgreSQL mode I cannot see any errors anymore.

Can somebody explain this magic above?

Comment: No he isn't... Your `@Before` method is executed in the same transaction and before executing a query state is synced with the database. Due to the read-only that cannot be done.

Comment: You mean my `@Before` method is executed in `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` as well? Why does it happen? Although I did not mark it.

Comment: It is executed as part of your test execution... It runs in the same transaction as your test method so that any changes can be rolled back after the test method. If that wouldn't be the case your test would pollute the database. Also an `@Before` method is executed before each `@Test` method. So if you have 5 `@Test` methods, your `@Before` will be run 5 times.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your explanation. But can I affect by some way on it? I mean that I want that each execution of `setUp` method be in its own transaction and would not be rolled back.

Comment: Don't make your method readonly or don't make it transactional but that will pollute your database. As the records remain after the test.

Comment: Pollution is not a problem in my case. I might use in-memory db (H2 db) or use test postgres db with `create-drop` strategy. As I wrote before If I did not make it  transactional I would get `LazyInitializationException`. And one notice yet. I have just copied my `testGet` method to second twin test method and marked both of them by  transactional anotation. Execution of first method was ok, but in second I got null reference here  `Foo foo = fooRepo.findOne(1L);`. I cannot understand it either.

Comment: The first one is rolled back. So the next id will be 2... Your second test will have a different ID.

Comment: Ohh. True. I've just fixed it by marking the first one as  `@Rollback(false)`. Thank you.

Comment: That might appear to fix things but you still have 2 records in your database... As each test invokes the setup. Also the ordering isn't garantueed to be the same. So instead you might want to mark your class `@Transactional` and `@Rollback(false)` instead of your individual methods. I suggest a read of http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#testing-tx .